# Jquery dotdotdot only fired properly on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In order to create an ellipsis after the second line within an element, I'm using  [jquery dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).
I'm using it with the [google font 'source sans pro'](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro), however it doesn't work properly until after the window is resized.

this is how the text appears before the window is resized (the ellipsis is created too early)

[image: text before window resize]

this is how the text appears after the window is resized (the ellipsis is in the proper position)

[image: text after window resize]

(I'm assuming this is happening because the font isn't fully loaded on the page's load, but I could be wrong?)

This is the way that I call the jquery dotdotdot.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        doResize();
        $(window).on('resize', doResize);
    });
    function doResize() {
        $(".col-mid a").dotdotdot({
            ellipsis: '...',
            height  : 40
        });
    }
```

How would I make it so it works properly? I've tried delaying the time that the dotdotdot function is called but this seems hacky, and like a bad solution.

[Here's a jsfiddle of relevant code.](http://jsfiddle.net/uXTSE/) (Weirdly enough it seems to work fine on jsfiddle, however it doesn't work on my computer.)

Comment: whether the target elements are present in the dom when the page is loaded initially

Comment: Yes everything's in the dom when the page loads initially, just like in this example.

Comment: as a debugging step can try `setTimeout(doResize, 1000)` instead of `doResize()`

Comment: Add the option `watch: true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works after resize you can trigger resize on page load and solve your problem:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

**OR**

Try embedding your code within:

```
$(window).load(function(){   });
```

Because thats how the code is displayed in the source of jsfiddle and you mentioned that its working in jsfiddle.Therefore give it a try.

Change your script code to:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        doResize();
        $(window).on('resize', doResize);
    });
    function doResize() {
        $("a").dotdotdot({
            ellipsis: '...',
            height  : 60
        });
    }

});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //doResize();
        $(window).on('load resize', doResize);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone ends up here two years after this question was posted (...like I just did because I had the same problem):

You don't need to trigger a resize() function. You can solve this problem with pure CSS:

Just choose a different (websafe) fallback font for your webfont. The fallback font should render similar/ as wide as your webfont so that the text-elements take the same space before and after your webfont is fully loaded.

For 'Source Sans Pro', '"Times New Roman", Times, serif' is probably the best option. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Answer (score 1):

The best and only solution I found is this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery("a").trigger("update.dot");
});
```

This solution is taken by the code proposed for the next versione (1.7.5) of dotdotdot. You can see it here: [Added functionality to use CSS classes without need of JS programming and added some more features](https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.dotdotdot/pull/96/files)

Comment: The only working solution and it was downvoted, amazing..

Thanks Giucas!

Answer (score 0):

You can add option through dotodotdot by  watch: 'window'

```
$(".content-class").dotdotdot({
    ellipsis    : '... ',
    watch       : 'window',
});
```

Comment: This property is the correct fix, but for font loading issues you need to set `watch: true`, which watches the element itself for resizing (once the new font is loaded) and not just the window.